# How to move the positive column into another column?

Tags: sql, t-sql, case-when

I have to segregate the positive and negative value into different column, I know I can achieve this by using CASE WHEN statement, but it turns out with error "Invalid column name TBAmt". 
Below is my SQL code, can anyone advise? thanks

```
SELECT 
B.ACCTFMTTD, B.ACCTDESC, A.FSCSYR, A.CURNTYPE, (A.OPENBAL + A.NETPERD1 + A.NETPERD2 + A.NETPERD3 + A.NETPERD4 + A.NETPERD5 + A.NETPERD6 + A.NETPERD7 + A.NETPERD8 + A.NETPERD9 + A.NETPERD10 + A.NETPERD11 + A.NETPERD12 + A.NETPERD13 + A.NETPERD14) AS TBAmt,

CASE WHEN [TBAmt] > 0 THEN [TBAmt] ELSE 0 END AS Debit,
CASE WHEN [TBAmt] < 0 THEN [TBAmt] ELSE 0 END AS Credit

FROM GLAFS AS A LEFT JOIN GLAMF AS B ON A.ACCTID = B.ACCTID
where 
A.FSCSYR = '2018' AND A.CURNTYPE = 'F'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write it as a sub query if you want to use the self constructed column `TBAmt`

```
SELECT
   CASE WHEN [TBAmt] > 0 THEN [TBAmt] ELSE 0 END AS Debit,
   CASE WHEN [TBAmt] < 0 THEN [TBAmt] ELSE 0 END AS Credit
FROM
(
   SELECT 
      B.ACCTFMTTD, B.ACCTDESC, A.FSCSYR, A.CURNTYPE, (A.OPENBAL + A.NETPERD1 + A.NETPERD2 + A.NETPERD3 + A.NETPERD4 + A.NETPERD5 + A.NETPERD6 + A.NETPERD7 + A.NETPERD8 + A.NETPERD9 + A.NETPERD10 + A.NETPERD11 + A.NETPERD12 + A.NETPERD13 + A.NETPERD14) AS TBAmt

   FROM GLAFS AS A LEFT JOIN GLAMF AS B ON A.ACCTID = B.ACCTID
   where 
      A.FSCSYR = '2018' AND A.CURNTYPE = 'F'
) tbl
```

Comment: Why can't I make it in one statement? Thanks anyway

Comment: You cant use columns that you have constructed yourself in the same select statement, you have to use a sub query,

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server allows you to declare such expressions using a lateral join (i.e. `apply`):

```
SELECT AM.ACCTFMTTD, AM.ACCTDESC,
       AF.FSCSYR, AF.CURNTYPE, V.TBAmt,
       (CASE WHEN V.TBAmt > 0 THEN TBAmt ELSE 0 END) AS Debit,
       (CASE WHEN V.TBAmt < 0 THEN TBAmt ELSE 0 END) AS Credit
FROM GLAFS AF LEFT JOIN
     GLAMF AM
     ON AF.ACCTID = AM.ACCTID CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (AF.OPENBAL + AF.NETPERD1 + AF.NETPERD2 + AF.NETPERD3 + AF.NETPERD4 + AF.NETPERD5 + AF.NETPERD6 + AF.NETPERD7 + AF.NETPERD8 + AF.NETPERD9 + AF.NETPERD10 + AF.NETPERD11 + AF.NETPERD12 + AF.NETPERD13 + AF.NETPERD14)
     ) V(v.TBAmt)
WHERE AF.FSCSYR = '2018' AND AF.CURNTYPE = 'F';
```

You should also use meaningful table aliases rather than arbitrary letters such as `A` and `B`.